# Web App on iOS loses session when Add To Home Screen

Tags: ios, web-applications

I made a Web App (Lotus Domino) in which the user needs to be authenticated to use. 
This works fine except when the solution is used in "Add To Home Screen" mode.
Every time the user switches to the Web App the user needs to login again to be authenticated. What can I do to make the session kept when added to home screen - like the App does when using the browser?
Some other questions on the same topic but none that I found giving me an answer on this one.